# Using bytes.Buffer with csv.writer

Tags: csv, go

I'm currently trying to serialize some string slice in a CSV without saving output to a file. I saw some examples using bytes.Buffer but even my the smallest test doesn't work. I don't know how to debug this, the code compiles without warning and doesn't throw error after writer.Flush(). It also works correctly with saving result to a file or piping it directly to standard output

Any help would be appreciated :)
Thx.

PS: the final print is just a test. I know i can use csv.NewWriter(os.stdout) to do so (and it works) but it doesn't fit my needs. I really would like to get the result in a byte array.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    writer := csv.NewWriter(&buffer)
    writer.Write([]string{"1", "2", "3", "4"})
    writer.Write([]string{"5", "6", "7", "8"})

    defer writer.Flush()
    if err := writer.Error(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(buffer.Bytes())
}
```

Comment: Try flushing without `defer`.

Comment: Call `writer.Flush()` before fetching the bytes from the buffer.  Do this by using a direct call instead of deferred call.

Comment: defer is nice, but it doesn't do magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are deferring the Flush call, making it execute after the fmt.Println call. Call Flush immediately:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    writer := csv.NewWriter(&buffer)
    writer.Write([]string{"1", "2", "3", "4"})
    writer.Write([]string{"5", "6", "7", "8"})

    writer.Flush()
    if err := writer.Error(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(buffer.String())
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BHTyfsuf0tY